# Construct a 3D matrix with linear index

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to construct a 3D matrix of size = `80 * 80 * 2` based on a set of data:

```
 1        4532   1257.0
 1        4556   1257.0
 1        4622   257.0
 1        4633   257.0
 2        7723   31.0
 2        8024   31.0
 2        8099   31.0
 2        9800   31.0
 2        8524   34.0
 2        8525   34.0
 2        8700   734.0
 2        8701   734.0
```

- The first column denotes the slice of matrix.
- The second column denotes the linear index of the matrix.
- The third column denotes the values of the elements.

---

What I'm doing now is: I first obtain two `80 * 80` 2D matrices `A` and `B` and then concatenate them using `cat(3, A, B)`:

Denote the above data be `M`.

```
for i = 1 : size(M,1)
    if (M(:,1)==1)
        [r c]=ind2sub(M(:,2));
        A = accumarray([r c], M(:,3));
    elseif (M(:,1)==2)
        [r c]=ind2sub(M(:,2));
        B = accumarray([r c], M(:,3));
    end
end

cat(3, A, B)
```

I am curious if there is any solutions that can build the `80*80*2` matrix merely by the linear index (the second column of my data) or any other simpler solution works for the purpose.

I appreciate for your help.

Comment: 80*80=6400. How can the linear index be >6400?

Comment: @stewie for my 3d matrix, it will be 80*80*2.

Comment: subtracting 6400 for the second column if `2` appears at the first column seems to be what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm assuming your example data is incorrect, and that all values in column 2 are less than `n*n`, where `nxn` is the size of the matrix (80x80 in your case).

If that's the case, the following two lines should do the trick.

```
out = zeros(n,n,2);
out((M(:,1)-1).*n^2+M(:,2)) = M(:,3)
```

If the second column contains values up to 2*n*n, and thus are the linear indices, then:

```
out = zeros(n,n,2);
out(M(:,2)) = M(:,3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your second solution is what my data means and it does work.